# CodeMirror change Handler not working (Javascript basics)

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am currently learning javascript and to do so I have started to work on a small code editor project based on the CodeMirror editor. Right now I am trying to implement a hsaEditorChanged():boolean method that returns true when the editor's content was changed from before and no change have happened for the past second. When I run this code my chrome js console gives the below exception :`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` at line 71 :
`e.docLastChanged = new Date.getTime();` . Due to my lack of knowledge in js ,I could not find out what the problem was although it's probably a really dumb one...

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks so much!

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    //...
});

editor.docLastChanged = new Date().getTime();
editor.hasChanged = true;

editor.hasEditorChanged = function(){
    var t = new Date().getTime();
    if ((t - editor.docLastChanged) > 1000 && editor.hasChanged) { //if no change for 1 sec
        editor.hasChanged = false;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
//register onChange handler to update the editor.docLastChanged variable
var changeHandler = function(e){
    e.docLastChanged = new Date.getTime(); //ERROR HERE.
    e.hasChanged = true;
    console.log("changed");
}

editor.on('change', changeHandler(this));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence of `new` is lower than that of the dot, so you're doing `new (Date.getTime)()`. Change your code to `(new Date).getTime()` or simply `+new Date` to get a millisecond timestamp.

Comment: He could also use `new Date().getTime()` instead

Comment: Tanks ! You are absolutely correct! I have forgot to add a `()`